# Using OpenType font with `dvilualatex` and `dvisvgm`

Tags: luatex, opentype, dvisvgm

From the manual page of `dvisvgm` I learned that `dvisvgm` can convert and embed OpenType fonts in SVG output.

Indeed, this perfectly works with the example code listed below, if I process it with

```
xelatex --no-pdf example
dvisvgm --zoom=-1 --exact --font-format=woff2 example.xdv
```

However, for a different purpose I need the capabilities of the Lua scripting language. So I decided to use `dvilualatex` for generating the intermediate DVI:

```
dvilualatex example
dvisvgm --zoom=-1 --exact --font-format=woff2 example.dvi
```

Unfortunately, `dvisvgm` fails on the DVI:

```
WARNING: font file '[FontAwesome5Free-Solid-900.otf]:script=latn;' not found
```

`example.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}
\faArrowRight\faArrowLeft
\end{document}
```

What do I have to adjust in order to use OTF with `dvilualatex` and `dvisvgm`?

Comment: From `dviasm` output I can see that the DVI file produced by XeLaTeX contains full path to the font, while the one created by LuaLaTeX just font name. So perhaps it is just that `dvisvgm` doesn't know how to find OpenType fonts by the filename?

Comment: dvisvgm doesn't support the extended font selection syntax used by LuaTeX. Also, unlike XeTeX, LuaTeX references glyphs by Unicode points instead of glyph indices. All glyphs not covered in the Unicode mapping table of the font, like big math operators or alternative symbols, get random character codes in the DVI file and therefore can't be determined by dvisvgm. Because of this, I haven't delved deeper into LuaTeX DVI files so far.

Comment: @Martin we discussed the problem with the character codes in the chat. Would it help if luatex would output some mapping between the GID and the character codes?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, that would be phantastic. But since the GIDs are local to the font file, it's probably necessary to store the path of that file too. The latter would also vastly simplify the file lookup of the font files, which currently requires the evaluation of LuaTeX font database from what I understand.

Comment: @Martin I have some code ready which would output the correct GIDs and the path. Do you need any indication that the font is a OpenType instead of a TFM font? Maybe a magic checksum?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger That sounds great. Yes, it would be helpful to have this information available if it can't be reliably derived from the file name suffix.

Comment: @Martin I uploaded a [draft to a GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/zauguin/16acd354ee07a909210895f63bc3acb0). Basically a font with the magic checksum 0x4c756146 ('LuaF') should be interpreted as a native font. The filename is passed  as fontname, all character indices are GIDs.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Great, some first tests look really promising. All required data is now present in the DVI file. I'll try some more complex files in the next couple of days as I'm quite busy at the moment. Thanks for your work on this!

Comment: @Martin Great. If you find some time, you can also let me know how attributes like the fontid for font collections or attributes like embolden/slant/extend should be passed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106428/discussion-between-martin-and-marcel-kruger).

Comment: @Martin I just discovered that `dvilualatex`+OTF font+`dvisvgm` now works like a charm! Thank you so much for this improvement! Maybe we can close this topic? (Though I am not sure whether this feature has arrived in (vanilla) TeXLive yet; I built the GitHub version of `dvisvgm` several times in the meantime and copied the binary to the TeXLive tree.)

Comment: @AlexG You're welcome. :-) This feature is available as of dvisvgm 2.10 which is not yet present in TeX Live as far as I know.